# Why isn't Mobile Safari showing image after window.onload?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I'm seeing unexpected behavior when trying to redirect users *only after* an image has finished loading on (latest) Mobile Safari. Ideally, the user would see the branded image, so they know they're in the correct place before being redirected.

From what I'm seeing, the `window.onload` event has fired, but the image still isn't being displayed prior to the user seeing the iOS confirmation prompt which says something like, "You are being redirected ...". This seems to be the worst of all worlds: the user (seemingly) has to wait for the page/image to load, but they're still not seeing it.

Here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
function main() {
  if (shouldRedirect()) {
    window.location = appStoreUrl;
  }
}

window.onload = main;

// I have also tried the following, which displays the same behavior
var src = "IMAGE-URL";
var image = new Image();
image.onload = main;
image.setAttribute('src', src);
```

So, is Safari being clever and not actually downloading/displaying the image because it knows the user might not *need* to see it? Alternatively, might this be a bug in Safari?

Comment: Try using ```window.location.href = appStoreUrl```

Comment: You're saying that using that property will result in the image being displayed prior to the redirect?

Comment: Try using ```image.src``` instead of setAttribute

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't, also from the code it looks like you're not adding the image to the document, or am i mistaken and that is somewhere else in your code

Comment: The image is being rendered on the server. The second approach is a kludge, but because it's using the same URL as the rendered image, the image should be loaded/displayed by the time its callback fires.